# Unable to append description to user in AD

Tags: powershell

I wrote a small loop to append description per users

```
ForEach ($usr in $users)
{   
    get-aduser $usr -Properties Description | Set-ADUser $usr -Description "$($_.Description) Need to be moved to OU Disabled"
```

But i got an error

"get-aduser : Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Can you please tell me why ? What should i do to append description to existing one?

Variable $users contains samaccount names (a list from csv file as below)

SamAccountName,FirstName,Lastname

test,test,test,

Comment: It depends pretty much on what's in your variable `$users`. You should show the relevant part of your code. You might (re)read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Variable $users contains samaccount names (a list from csv file)

Comment: So you should use either `ForEach ($usr in $users.sAMAccountName)` or `get-aduser $usr.sAMAccountName` ... and for Set-ADUser you don't need to specify `$usr` again ... you already did before the pipe! ;-)